# Async request into for loop angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array and i need to send values of array to webservice through http post request one by one . For the node.js , i'm using "async" package to do that for ex: `async.eachSeries` doing it well , how can i do that same thing for angular.js , my normal  async code;

```
//this code sends all queries of array (maybe  5.000 request at same time , it is hard to process for webservice :=) ) at same time and wait for all responses. 
//it works but actually for me , responses should wait others at end of loop should work one by one 
//like async.eachSeries module!

    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.lenght; i++) {
        (function (i) {
                var data = {
                    "myQuery": myArr[i].query
                };
                $http.post("/myServiceUrl", data).success(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                });
        })(i);
}
```

Both **Matt Way** and **Chris L** answers **Correct** , you can investigate Chris's answer for understanding about async to sync functions in for loops.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: you can use the `async` package in the browser with angular's `$http`. The only issue you'll have is if you want to update your `$scope` with your results then you may need to use `$scope.$apply` or `$timeout` (without the  optional delay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$q` to create a similar requirement by chaining promises together. For example:

```
var chain = $q.when();
angular.forEach(myArr, function(item){
    chain = chain.then(function(){
        var data = {
            myQuery: item.query
        };
        return $http.post('/myServiceUrl', data).success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});

// the final chain object will resolve once all the posts have completed.
chain.then(function(){
    console.log('all done!');
});
```

Essentially you are just running the next promise once the previous one has completed. Emphasis here on the fact that each request will wait until the previous one has completed, as per your question.

Comment: i tried to use this but i didn't get any reaction from system , maybe it is about my angular.js version is old one . Should i add "$q" into "app.controller" ?

Comment: $q is angular's promise library, and was in angular from the beginning. Promises are by far the correct way to use `$http`, not the convoluted answer you marked as correct. If you create a fiddle, we can help you.

Comment: @MattWay the problem with the q library comes when you are performing large sequential calculations and manipulating data in a sequential manner requiring error handling to alert user to provide more input, etc. It depends on your use case and your blanket statement is not entirely correct based on my attempts at implementation in a statistical calculation application

Comment: Your comment makes no sense? What does this question have to do with 'large sequential calculations'? Osman wanted to perform a chain of `$http` calls, and this answer does that using promises, which was the intention of `$q`. I am curious about your belief of problems with `$q` though, it would probably make a good question.

Comment: I was thinking about re-posting it as a question. When I get time I will. However, there are time, depending on use case (which this person did not entirely expand on) where you want to do what I did. I gave an example of that because I ran into it in my own development and it required me to do something like this. I will dig into the $q source code before posting a question about it. :-) I'm just saying, use case determines the best approach, not just "best practices" and "angular, because..."

Comment: ps. @MattWay . I am still relatively new myself. I am having this discussion to learn from more experienced developers. Please don't interpret my conversation as "arguing" as much as it is prying into more experienced minds. It is tough to make this clear in text. Sincerely, Chris

Comment: The asynchronous discussion makes it difficult to have a good conversation. If only there were some way to make it synchronous! ;-)

Comment: Hey my friends , this answer also true , it is working like Chris's answer .I think , alternatively Chris's answer more useful for learning this logic but we can use $q  to do this cause it is stable version of angularjs and thank you so much both of you , i have alternative solutions now , thank you :)

Comment: Hey Osman, if it works for you use it. please see my edited answer with the jsfiddle that shows the difference between the two answers. :-D

Comment: Okay bro , i investigated and i am thinking to create a async module for angular now :P , it is very illustrative , i wish i can choose both answers as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. You want to run a for loop in a synchronized manner such that the next iteration only occurs once the previous iteration is completed. For that, you can use a synchronized loop/callbacks. Especially if the order matters.

```
        var syncLoop = function (iterations, process, exit) {
            var index = 0,
                done = false,
                shouldExit = false;
            var loop = {
                next: function () {
                    if (done) {
                        if (shouldExit && exit) {
                            return exit(); // Exit if we're done
                        }
                    }
                    // If we're not finished
                    if (index < iterations) {
                        index++; // Increment our index
                        process(loop); // Run our process, pass in the loop
                        // Otherwise we're done
                    } else {
                        done = true; // Make sure we say we're done
                        if (exit) exit(); // Call the callback on exit
                    }
                },
                iteration: function () {
                    return index - 1; // Return the loop number we're on
                },
                break: function (end) {
                    done = true; // End the loop
                    shouldExit = end; // Passing end as true means we still call the exit callback
                }
            };
            console.log('running first time');
            loop.next();
            return loop;
        }
```

For your particular implementation:

```
    syncLoop(myArray.length, function (loop) {
        var index = loop.iteration();
        var data = {
            "myQuery": myArray[index].query
        };
        $http.post("/myServiceUrl", data).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            loop.next();
        });
    }, function () {
        console.log('done');
    });
```

If you intend on doing something with the data once returned (such as perform calculations) you can do so with this method because you will return the data in a specified order.

I implemented something similar in a statistical calculation web app I built.

**EDIT:**

To illustrate the problem I had when using $q.when I have set up a fiddle. Hopefully this will help illustrate why I did this the way I did.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/6atp3w8o/

Using the following code from Matt's answer:

```
var chain = $q.when(promise.getResult());
    angular.forEach(myArr, function (item) {
        chain = chain.then(function () {
            $rootScope.status = item;
            console.log(item);
        });
    });

    // the final chain object will resolve once all the posts have completed.
    chain.then(function () {
        console.log('all done!');
    });
```

And this fiddle is an example of my solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/Lgwteone/3/

Compare the $q version to my version. View the console and imagine those being delivered to the user interface for user intervention in the process and/or performing statistical operations on the sequential returns.

You will see that it does not sequentially give the numbers 1,2,3,4 etc. either in the console or in the view in Matt's answer. It 'batches' the responses and then returns them. Therefore, if step 3 is not to be run depending on the response in step 2 there is not, at least in the answer provided, a way to break out or explicitly control the synchronous operation here. This presents a significant problem when attempting to perform sequential calculations and/or allow the user to control break points, etc.

Now, I am digging through both the $q libraries and the Q library to see if there is a more elegant solution for this problem. However, my solution does work as requested and is very explicit which allows me to place the function in a service and manipulate for certain use cases at my will because I completely understand what it is doing. For me, that is more important than using a library (at least at this stage in my development as a programmer and I am sure there are lots of other people at the same stage on StackOverflow as well).

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question?

Comment: its okay , every request's reponses wait eachother with this code , thank you for your great help :) ,Moreover , this answer will be very useful for others .

Comment: While this answer technically works, it is not a good choice of solution.

Comment: Im sorry you seem so upset with my answer @MattWay . Perhaps if you give a fiddle, performing data driven calculations in a defined sequential orders with error handling and show it to us you could enlighten both of us instead of just saying "it works but its not good." This is a learning experience for everyone, CONSTRUCTIVE criticism is  the entire point of participating here. :-)

Comment: I did provide a more correct answer. What you have written is basically a simplified custom version of what $q does for you anyway. Would you agree that reinventing the wheel may not be the best approach?

Comment: absolutely! I hate reinventing the wheel. However, when I tried using $q the synchronicity was not perfect and I could not perform sequential calculations and then, if calculation result =  or if result undefined provide an error for the user to handle and then resume sequential calculations.

Answer (score 1):

```
function logResultFromWebService(value)
{
    $http.post("/myServiceUrl", value).success(console.log);
}

angular.forEach(myArray, logResultFromWebService);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter in which they are sent

```
var items = [/* your array */];
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(items, function(value, key){
    var promise = $http.post("/myServiceUrl", { "myQuery": value.query });
    promises.push(promise);
});
return $q.all(promises);
```

Comment: I believe this will still send all requests simultaneously, and is not about order.