# Closure in for loop with HTTP request

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, callback, closures

I have a `for` loop in which I call a function. This function makes an HTTP request and provides an object through a callback.  In the `for` loop however, I tried to bind the `index` with a closure. But it doesn't work. The `index` seems to be always the same. What is wrong in my code?

```
for(var y = 0; y < caps.length; y++) {
    (function(index) {
        getChildContent(caps[index], function(content) {
            var child = {};
            child.FunctionName = caps[index];
            child.Content = [];
            child.Content.push(content);
            parent.Functions.push(child);       
            console.log(content);
        }); 
    })(y);      
}
```

@treeno this is the getChildContent function:

```
function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
t = capname.replace(' ', '_');
bot.page(t).complete(function (title, text, date) {
    var str = S(text).between('== Kurzbeschreibung ==\n* ', '.').s;
        if(str === undefined || str === null || str === '') {
            throw new Error('Undefined, Null or Empty!');
        }
        else {
            var content = {};
            str = parseTitles(str);
            content.Owner = str[0];
            content.Aim = str[1];
            content.What = str[2];
            content.Who = str[3];
            content.Steps = str[4];
            content.Page = 'someURL';
            callback(content);
        }
});
```

}

Comment: How have you checked if the `index` is the same (as on the face of it, this code seems to be correct)? If you add a `console.log(index)` next to your other `console.log`, do you see the same `index`?

Comment: can you also show getChildContent()? Maybe it stores the passed function always in the same object, so, that you overwrite the function in each iteration... so that you always end up with the last function... just a guess...

Comment: @treeno i edited the OP and added the getChildContent() function

Comment: @JamesThorpe because the console.log(content) always prints out the  last content object....

Comment: Try var t = capname.replace(' ', '_');

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the index,

the ajax response time is just different so it will not be in order

like so:

```
function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
  // simulate ajax call with random response time
  setTimeout( function () {
      var content='pizza';
      callback(content);
  }, (Math.random(0,1000)*1000));
}

var parent = { Functions: [] };
var caps = ['lol', 'lol2', 'haha'];

    for(var y = 0; y < caps.length; y++) {
       (function(index) {
           console.log(index);
           getChildContent(caps[index], function(content) {
              var child = {};
              child.FunctionName = caps[index];
              child.Content = [];
              child.Content.push(content);
              parent.Functions.push(child);       
              console.log(content, index, caps[index]);
          }); 
      })(y);
    }

// Outputs:
// These are the indexes (Yes, they are in order)
// 0
// 1
// 2
// These are the responses (The order is based from the request completion time)
// pizza 1 lol2
// pizza 2 haha
// pizza 0 lol
```

[UPDATE]

There's a work around to make the way you want but its gonna wait until all the responses is finished.

```
 function waitLoadCompleted( callback ) {
  if( loaded == caps.length ) {
     // do stuff 
     callback( );
  }
 }

function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
  // simulate ajax call with random response time
  setTimeout( function () {
      var content='pizza';
      callback(content);
  }, (Math.random(0,1000)*1000));
}

var loaded = 0;
var tempcontainer = [];
var parent = { Functions: [] };
var caps = ['lol', 'lol2', 'haha'];

    for(var y = 0; y < caps.length; y++) {
       (function(index) {
           console.log(index);
           getChildContent(caps[index], function(content) {

              loaded++;                  
              tempcontainer.push({ index: index, data: content });

              waitLoadCompleted(function(){
                // everything is loaded
                tempcontainer.sort(function(a, b) { return a.index - b.index; });

                for( i in tempcontainer ) {
                  var index = tempcontainer[i].index;
                  var child = {};
                  child.FunctionName = caps[index];
                  child.Content = [];
                  child.Content.push(content);
                  parent.Functions.push(child);       
                  console.log(content, index, caps[index]);
                }                    
              })

          }); 
      })(y);
    }

// Outputs:
// 0
// 1
// 2
// pizza 0 lol
// pizza 1 lol2
// pizza 2 haha
```

[UPDATE]

Another solution is to segment it to a set of responses and make it seem like everthings in order by sorting the collected responses
E.g. like FB posts, chat etc. a type where responses never ends

```
function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
  // simulate ajax call with random response time
  setTimeout( function () {
      var content='pizza';
      callback(content);
  }, (Math.random(0,1000)*1000));
}

var tempcontainer = [];
var parent = { Functions: [] };
var caps = ['lol', 'lol2', 'haha'];

    for(var y = 0; y < caps.length; y++) {
       (function(index) {
           console.log(index);
           getChildContent(caps[index], function(content) {

              tempcontainer.push({ index: index, data: content });
              tempcontainer.sort(function(a, b) { return a.index - b.index; });

              for( i in tempcontainer ) {
                  var child = {};
                  child.FunctionName = caps[index];
                  child.Content = [];
                  child.Content.push(content);
                  parent.Functions.push(child);       
                  console.log(content, tempcontainer[i].index, caps[tempcontainer[i].index]);
              }

              console.log("<--SET RESPONSE-->");                 
          }); 
      })(y);
    }

        // Outputs:
        // 0
        // 1
        // 2
        // pizza 1 lol2
        // <--SET RESPONSE-->
        // pizza 0 lol
        // pizza 1 lol2
        // <--SET RESPONSE-->
        // pizza 0 lol
        // pizza 1 lol2
        // pizza 2 haha
        // <--SET RESPONSE-->
```

Comment: thanks for your effort! good to know that the code is okay... but is there a way to get everything in order?

Comment: what are you doing with the data? If it is important that each step be performed sequentially then a synchronized loop might be better. Let me know if this solution (which waits for all returns and then reorders them) doesn't work for you and I'll show you my solution I have used to perform these thing sequentially in case you need to do calculations, etc. Although, I don't see anything wrong with this solution at first glance depending on use case.

Comment: It works, I just tested it from this browser console, btw I posted another alternative solution that doesn't wait for everything but still outputs the responses in order. @ChrisL

Comment: thanks for your effort guys!! It works but it's not in order and i get duplicates....   Would your sequentially approach solve my problem? @ChrisL

Comment: probably, take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/Lgwteone/ and this stack overflow answer of mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181502/async-request-into-for-loop-angular-js/33181792#33181792     if you need more explanation just send me a chat request.

Comment: i've watched over your answer... further explanation and some hints on how to implement this in my specific example above would be great!  But i can't sent u a chat request as i have not enough reputation points..... @ChrisL

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle so I can give you code that I know will work for you?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93116/sync-loop meet me there, give me an @mention so I can understand exactly how to help you. :-D

Comment: thanks man!!! here's a jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zxpqqryL/  ...the console.log(content) should print out 12 different objects, in order if possible. what i get with this code are more than 12 objects, duplicates and not in order.... sry for talking here again, but i can't chat in your room as i need 20 reputation points to be able to chat on stackoverflow :D ...